When I click on the edit button, I want the editing table at the bottom of the page to open, but somehow it does not appear
When I click on the edit button, I want the editing table at the bottom of the page to open, but somehow it does not appear.
display:none When I deleteit, the table below appears, but I want it to appear when I click the button.
        echo '<td>';         echo '<button class="updateBtn" onclick="toggleUpdateForm(' . $row['id'] . ')">';         echo '<i class="fa-solid fa-pen" style="color: #0a0a0a;"></i>';         echo '</button>';

<!-- Güncelleme Formu -->
<div class="container" style="display:none;" id="updateFormContainer">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="update-form p-3">
            <h2>Veri Güncelle</h2>
            <form id="updateForm" action="guncelle.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" id="updateId" name="id">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="updateName" class="form-label">First:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateName" name="name">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="updateDate" class="form-label">Date Created:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateDate" name="date">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="updateRole" class="form-label">Role:</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="updateRole" name="role">
                        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                        <option value="Publisher">Publisher</option>    
                        <option value="Modaratör">Modaratör</option>
                        <option value="Tester">Tester</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="updateStatus" class="form-label">Status:</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="updateStatus" name="status">
                        <option value="Inactive">İnaktif</option>
                        <option value="Idle">Boşta</option>
                        <option value="Active">Aktif</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Güncelle</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="cancelUpdate()">İptal</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function toggleUpdateForm(id) {
    var updateFormContainer = document.getElementById('updateFormContainer');
    var updateIdField = document.getElementById('updateId');
    var updateFormDisplay = window.getComputedStyle(updateFormContainer).display;

    // Eğer güncelleme formu zaten görünürse ve güncellenen ID aynı ise, iptal edilmiş gibi kabul edip formu gizle
    if (updateFormDisplay === 'block' && updateIdField.value === id) {
        updateFormContainer.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        // Formu doldur
        var row = document.querySelector('tr:nth-child(' + (id + 1) + ')');
        var cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');

        updateIdField.value = id;
        document.getElementById('updateName').value = cells[1].innerText;
        document.getElementById('updateDate').value = cells[2].innerText;
        document.getElementById('updateRole').value = cells[3].innerText;
        document.getElementById('updateStatus').value = cells[4].innerText;

        // Formu göster
        updateFormContainer.style.display = 'block';
    }
}


Why do you keep saying the same thing over and over?

Instead of assigning to .style.display, I recommend you use a CSS class.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.
